# TextinputLayout color

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

Is there any chance we could change the color of the bottom line of the TextinputLayout without twiking the theme (neither using the (android/app):theme attribut on the view).

Can't we just do it through a style attribut on the TextInputLayout or it's *EditText son ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles and themes are completely different. The only way to change a color pulled from a theme (such as is the case with `colorAccent` and `TextInputLayout`) is to apply a theme, either to the view with `android:theme` or to the entire Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
Then it isn't possible to do it without a theme. I just wanted to double check.